# vSphere HTML5 interface not showing hosts and virtual machines

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I have a vcenter setup which I'm accessing using the HTML5 interface. Since a couple of days, the client is empty (not displaying the hosts or VMs or datastores). This happens on all browsers I tried.

In the browser console, I see:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location:
>   https://10.16.2.99/ui/navigator/navigate/tree Line Number 1, Column 1:

Below how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the `vsphere-client` service? This is the service assigned to the vSphere (HTML5) Web Client.

Some examples on how to do this: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2109887

Comment: It's `vsphere-ui` not `vsphere-client`.